# google maps heatmap shows blurred green instead specific red areas

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using the original Google Maps heatmap example and it works fine.

I took it from this page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap#maps_layer_heatmap-javascript

The problem is after applying my points. I just added 2k new points the sameway as the example:

```
    new google.maps.LatLng(xxx, xxx),
```

Instead showing the certain red areas, it becomes a unique big blurred green area.

Example at: https://jsfiddle.net/d4xerj7L/2/

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a [maxIntensity](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/visualization#HeatmapLayerOptions.maxIntensity).

```js
heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: getPoints(),
    map: map,
    maxIntensity: 4, // <---  added this
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d4xerj7L/2/

[image]